# Expansion of power series given an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to solve a problem that poses the following questions

A power series expansion for $\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+\ln(x+1)}{x^3}dx$ is $\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a(n)}x^n+c$ find the value of $a(n)$.

What I did was to integrate what was given, such that
$$\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+\ln(x+1)}{x^3}dx=\dfrac{\left(x^2-1\right)\ln\left(x+1\right)+x}{2x^2}+c$$
In addition, using the fact that
$$x\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1} x^n$$

We can make the expression somewhat similar, but I don't know how I can arrive at the requested value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Recall the taylor series

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + \ldots$$

Then your integrand is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(1+x) - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^3} 
&= 
\frac{\left ( x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + \ldots \right ) - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^3} \\
&=
\frac{\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + \ldots}{x^3} \\
&=
\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}x + \ldots
\end{align}
$$

From here, you should integrate term-by-term (why is this allowed?) to get the answer.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Your answer was very helpful!